# What is a clan-fam?

Tags: the-dark-tower, terminology

While reading through [The Gunslinger](https://books.google.pt/books?id=uagODAAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=gunslinger%20inbred%20clan-fams&source=bl&ots=xR8yKssojg&sig=qmUG6D3iTPaEmItZOfhR5dyQiYA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3voKjwJXUAhXHZVAKHXXoAbQQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=gunslinger%20inbred%20clan-fams&f=false), I came across the following line in the 2nd paragraph of Chapter 5:

> sullen, inbred clan-fams, toiling silently in the fields by day.

I googled the term and it apparently has no (obvious) meaning. I also thought it might have been a typo of my e-version (originally *corn-farms*, perhaps?), but the link on Google Books I just posted has the same expression, so it seems unlikely. I'm guessing it is just an in-universe term.

## What are clan-fams?

*Please avoid spoilers regarding the book's plot. If necessary, use the spoiler tag in your answer.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While not ever actually explained, this is almost assuredly a portmanteau of "clan" and "family".

It refers to *families* of farmers who have *inbred*, creating small pocket *clans* that are largely self-sufficient and self-propagating.